# Installing ubuntu: creating swap space error

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, gparted, swap

I have a computer with windows 7 installed that's not booting and decided to install ubuntu on it. I've downloaded ubuntu on a mac and used `dd` to make a bootable usb. I'm able to boot from the usb and I choose `Install Ubuntu`.

I choose `Install Ubuntu`, `Erase Disk` and `Install now` but I get this error:

```
The creation of swap space in partition #5 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed.
```

So it seems some part of the system is corrupted. I may have mangled it even more trying to fix this. I've googled around and tried lots of solutions that didn't work for me:

- Instead of `Erase Disk` I choose `Something else`. I then try to set up partitions as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation). Clicking `Install now` gets me a bit further than before, but after staying on

  ```
  Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #5 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda)...
  ```

  for a while, I get this error:

  ```
  The ext4 file system creation in partition #6 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed
  ```

I Use `Try Ubuntu` instead and open a terminal. Then try the following:

- `sudo gparted`. It gives the following error:

  ```
  Invalid partition table on /dev/sda - wrong signature bfd3.
  ```

  clicking ignore gives

  ```
  The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
  ```

  I click ignore again and see three partitions:

  Partition  |  File System  |  Size    | Used  |  Unused  |  Flags

  /dev/sda1  |  linux-swap  | 590.18 GiB   |  0.00 B  | 590.18GiB |

  /dev/sda2  |  extended  | 5.99 GiB   |  -  | - |

  unallocated  |  unallocated  | 5.99 GiB   |  -  | - |

  I delete the partitions `sda1` and `sda2`. It repeats the two errors but it seems to have worked; the only thing partition left is `unallocated`. But after restarting and choosing `Install Ubuntu` I get the same errors. And using `Try Ubuntu` and `gparted` again the partitions are exactly like in the table above once more.
- I download `Boot Repair` and run it, as [explained here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It seems to work but after restart the problems are the same. The logs can be found [here](http://paste2.org/g7zmWjL6).
- I download `Testdisk` and run it as [explained here](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-fix-mangled-partition-table-linux). When running the `Analyse` I see the following:

  ```
   Disk /dev/sda - 640 GiB / 596 GiB - CHS 77825 255 63
   Current partition structure:
   Partition     Start    End    Size in sectors
   1 P Linux swap  0  32  33  62  53  55 997376
   2 E extended   62  86  23  77825  70  5  1249261570
  No partition is bootable
   5 L Linux   62  86 25 2493 172 47 39059456
    X Extended 2493 172 48 77825 70 5 1210202112

  test_logical
  Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55
  ```

  so the output is a bit different than in the link. I run `Quick Search` and get some of the same info again. I then have options to change partition characteristics and to add partition, load backup and change type, but I'm not sure what to do.
- Running `sudo LANG=C sfdisk -d /dev/sda` gives"

  ```
  Ignoring extra data in partition table 6
  Ignoring extra data in partition table 6
  Ignoring extra data in partition table 6
  Invalid flag 0x9616 of EBR (for partition 6) will be corrected by w(rite).
  label: dos
  label-id: 0x976074d3
  device: /dev/sda
  unit: sectors

  /dev/sda1 : start = 2048, size = 997376, type = 82
  /dev/sda2 : start = 1001470, size = 1249261570, type = 5
  /dev/sda5 : start = 1001472, size = 39059456, type = 83
  /dev/sda6 : start = 3022904410, size = 3562462754, type = 77
  ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Take backup of the contents of your hdd. If your hdd has physical damage, there is no way to fix it unfortunately.
Be warned, this will destroy all your data.

- Download `Ultimate Boot CD` and make a bootable disk.
- Make a second bootable device with Ubuntu with in it.
- Boot using UBCD, open GParted, manually delete all your drives
- Choose `Create Partition Table` from `Device`. Pick `DOS` from the dropdown and click apply.

This should fix the pesky `The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes` issue you were having.

- Quit Gparted, and run a suitable disk checking utility. Scroll down to `/HDD/Diagnosis` part in UBCD website for reference. Also [this step by step guide](http://us.informatiweb.net/tutorials/it/5-live-cd/82--ubcd-test-your-hardware.html) is good.

If disk checking apps doesn't pick up any bad sectors or errors,

- Quit UBCD, boot from the another bootable disk that has Ubuntu.
- Fresh install.

Comment: After choosing the UBCD as a boot device I just get a flashing dash, might be the hardware like you said. Thanks for trying!

Comment: @jorgen, you can try with the bootable ubuntu disk.  It has `gparted`, so you'll be able to completely remove and recreate the partition table. Then install ubuntu. However, all your data will be lost, so keep a backup first.

Comment: I think I tried that already (second bullet point in the OP), unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: @jorgen I'm sorry if I've misread, but what I understand from OP is you deleted the existing partition.  But it does not say if you have completed recreated the partition table (bulletpoint#4 of my answer). If you've done so, and still no luck, I think you should claim for your warranty.